# VertexIDs of vertex can collide or not, when you put several Janusserver

Tags: gremlin-server, janusgraph

I have a question. I would like to know if vertex IDs of vertex can collide or not, when you put several Janusserver inserting vertices against the same Cassandra?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**VertexIDs are unique across cluster**

JanusGraph IDs are 64 bit long

```
[ 0 | count | partition | ID padding (if any) ]
```

- ID padding : Based on the type of element
- Partition : Each janusgraph node uniquely allocate IDBlock for some (default 10) partition.
- Count : provide a local count from each IDBlock

Together with the count, partition and id padding the is ID unique across cluster

---

[image: JanusGraph Bit Format]

JanusGraph uses `ConsistentKeyIDAuthority` class to allocate IDBlock. IDBlock Consist of start count and block size (Default Value 10000). For each partition in a JanusGraph instance it locally increment count, starting from start count and assign maximum block size number of id.

A JanusGraph Instance have default 10 partition. These partition and IDBlock are initialized at startup, If a IDBlock id creating size exceeds the block size then it reallocate new IDBlock. If a partition's start count exceeds the max counter value, then it added to the exhausted partition.

JanusGraph uses cassandra `janusgraph_ids` table to allocate IDBlock.

Note : *All the term partition, IDBlock are JanusGraph specific*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

I do not understand the concept of partition.
Is an unique identifier by JanusServer/GremlinServer when connecting to Cassandra or is it related to the Cassandra partitioning key?.
What is IDBlock?
Each JanusServer has a distinct partition. Changes the default value from 10 to another by random?

Comment: Thank you very much again. I understood it perfectly